# How to force dataview item in EXTJS to maintain equal vertical space?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

How to customize CSS in order to force dataview (Ext.view.View - classic toolkit) item to be equaly distributed in vertical direction. I have dataview that I would like to present in two columns, but items are not of the same height. I would like to distribute them evenly in vertical direction. Since a picture is worth a thousand words, here is the picture of what i get and what I would like to achieve:

[image]

So, dataview aligns items vertically, but I would like that item 3 starts just below the item 1. Basically, I would like that items are poopulated orderly one below the other. I would also like to avoid having two dataviews (one for the left part and the other for right part).

Here is what I got so far:

**EXTJS code**:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('myModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'field1',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            id: 'myStore',
            model: 'myModel',
            data: [{
                field1: '1. Some short text.'
            }, {
                field1: '2. A little bit longer text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
            },{
                field1: '3. This is the item number 3. It is supposed to be under the item number 1.'
            },{
                field1: '4. Item number 4'
            }, {
                field1: '5. Item number 5. When item number 3. shifts up, this item shoul also be just below item nummber 3.'
            },]
        });
        store.load();

        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            frame: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 535,
            height: 310,
            resizable: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            renderTo: document.body,
            title: 'MyPanel',
            items: Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
                store: store,

                cls: 'my-view',
                itemCls: 'my-card',
                itemTpl: ['<div class="my-card-1">',
                            '{field1}',
                          '</div>'],
            })
        });
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.my-view {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.my-card {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: calc(30vw);
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.my-card-1 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

And the result corresponds to Figure 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column layout (or flex layout):

```
.my-view {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 50%;
}

.my-card {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.my-card-1 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```